# Enterprise library semantic logging block. SQLDatabase sink. Out of process

Tags: enterprise-library

I am using Enterprise library semantic logging block (out of process) and using SQL Database sink to dump all the message. After putting everything in place and doing a test run, I am getting the following error - could not find stored procedure 'dbo.WriteTraces'.

Anybody faced similar issue ? Pl suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of process semantic logging assembly comes with some powershell scripts and .sql files. We have to edit (to change DB name) and run these scripts. This will generate the stored procs and the associated table for us.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same error but it was because we were trying to use a schema other than dbo  for our logging database. Once we changed it back to dbo that resolved the problem. We were using the out of process SemanticLogging-svc.exe, which, from what I can tell, assumes that dbo is the schema name.